# audio_capture / audio_playback not working

Tags: ros, audio-common, roswtf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been following the ***audio_common*** [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/audio_common/Tutorials/Streaming%20audio).

I run:

```
gst-launch-0.10 alsasrc ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! alsasink
```

and it works correctly.

When I continue the next steps,

```
roslaunch audio_capture capture.launch

roslaunch audio_play play.launch
```

no sound is played back.

When I check the topics, **/audio** is there and generating values. **rxgraph** shows them connected. But, when I run **roswtf**, I get:

> ERROR The following nodes should be connected but aren't:

> * /audio_capture->/audio_play (/audio)

I am running on Natty.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11628/audio_capture-/-audio_playback-not-working/) by [River](https://answers.ros.org/users/549/river/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2011-10-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This sounds like a network setup issue. See http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-12-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0